# Possible to take a backup of SQL Server 2012 DB and restore on 2008?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2008, database, sql-server-2012

I want to take a backup of SQL 2012 and restore on 2008, is that possible ?

[image]

I have this options which I can't change on DB. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Not possible. Compatibility level talks of how the SQL behaves - not the database internal format.

I suggest you start standardizing your servers. THe requirement points to some highly disputable decisions - either to run outdated reserver machines, or to upgrade a production machine without planning.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not allow downgrading to an older version

You could use the Tasks ->Export wizard in 2012 instance, create an empty database and use Import wizard in 2008 instance, however this may hot be an ideal solution since the Export/Import wizard will not restore all objects (it will copy tables but not indexes, keys etc.)

For more possible options, and an explanation you can refer to this article:
[Why Can't I Restore a Database to an Older Version of SQL Server?](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2675/why-cant-i-restore-a-database-to-an-older-version-of-sql-server/)

Options suggested in the article are:

-Upgrade the older version of SQL Server to be at the same level as the newer SQL Server.

-Script out the objects from the newer database and then usp a bcp process to extract the data from the newer database and import it into the older database.

-Use the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to build an SSIS package to move the data (it will move the data only).

-Build a custom SSIS package to do the data move.

-Use replication to move the data from the newer database to the older one.

-Use some other form of scripting, such as with PowerShell, to keep the databases in sync.

Another option is to use third party tools, [ApexSQL Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx) and [ApexSQL Data Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx)

You can read detailed explanation of the process in this article:[Restoring SQL Server database backup to an older version of SQL Server](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/restore-sql-server-database-backup-to-older-version-of-sql-server/)

Other third party tools may help as well

Hope this helps

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*